# Use Selenium automation using perl

Tags: selenium, perl

I am in a requirement to download multiple files (from a private/internal network) on daily basis.
For which I intended to use selenium with perl to daily download the files from respective locations. I am very new to this domain and need your help.

As a sample program, i am trying to simply connect google.com but it is not getting connected.

```
    my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                          port => 80,
                          browser => "*iexplore",
                          browser_url => "http://www.google.com",
                        );
    $sel->start;
    $sel->open("http://www.google.com");
    $sel->type("q", "hello world");
    $sel->click("btnG");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load(5000);
    print $sel->get_title;
    $sel->stop;
```

ERROR - > Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/:
500 Can't connect to localhost:4444 (Bad address)

i changed the port to 80 and then i get error as:
Error requesting http://localhost:80/selenium-server/driver/:
404 Not Found

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is Selenium Server running on your machine?

Comment: no, havent installed the selenium server locally

Comment: What service is running on port 80 on localhost, then?

Comment: Re "*no, havent installed the selenium server locally*" No surprise you can't connect to it, then. Maybe use Selenium::Chrome instead?